# Targeting Root from a Movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, root, movieclip

Im having trouble targeting back to the main timeline from within a movie clip AS3.

I have tried the code below but still does nothing? I have labelled the frame in which I would like it to go to on the main time and added this code to the actions within in the movie clip, but when I click the button it does nothing? I have no errors come up?

Any ideas?

```
map_UK.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, MAIN);

function MAIN(e:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay("MAIN");
}
```

Comment: if you trace out "root" what does it print out? Is this written in a frame script?

Comment: Sorry im a newbie can you explain how?

Comment: Put in trace("root: "+ root); inside of your MAIN method. The concept of "root" doesn't really exist like it did in actionscript 2 (if you are familiar with that...), but I'm curious to see why the complier didn't put it as an error.

Comment: Like this...? map_UK.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, MAIN);

    function MAIN(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
 MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop("MAIN");
 trace('root: ' + root);
    }

Comment: yes, what gets printed out in the output panel when you click on "map_UK" ?

Comment: root: [object MainTimeline]

Comment: Oh, so "root" is an actual reference to the timeline. In that case, just try root.gotoAndPlay("MAIN"); without the movieclip casting. If that doesn't work, try replacing "MAIN" with the frame number to see if that is the issue.

Comment: Neither worked, am i right in putting this code within the actions on the movie clip not the main timeline?

Comment: Not to worry i have found another solution to my problem by changing visiblity on the clips, if you do find a solution to refering back to root let me know but thanks for your help.

Comment: gotoAndPlay will also work without any problem, but since i am not sure how you have put the frames use gotoAndStop().